# Passing arguments via url parameters inside include function in php

Tags: php

Suppose, I have an index.php file like this:

```
<?php
 $id=2;
 include('php/config.php');
 require_once "php/variables.php";
?>
```

Is there any way to pass the variable $id via url parameter to **config.php** and  **variables.php** files so that I can perform some tasks based on the variable after getting it
by $_GET['id']?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$id` in both file, because you are already including those two file in your current file so you can able to access `$id`, try to print `echo $id;` in both files and you can see the value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can directly access $id in both files as saied by Karthik.
Or you can use global variables

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> include('php/config.php');
> require_once "php/variables.php";
> ```

The `include` and `require_once` functions, take a *filesystem path* by default; not a URL. Consequently "URL parameters" (and the corresponding `$_GET` superglobal) are irrelevant here, because you are not passing a URL.

(Yes, you can pass a URL to these functions if you have the appropriate fopen wrappers set and this will trigger an HTTP request - but this is most probably not what you want to do here.)

The include and require_once functions include the referenced document in-place and therefore inherit the current scope. Consequently the `$id` variable will be available as-is to these included scripts (as the other answers have already pointed out).